# Call to a member function checkLearning() on null (View:

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-7

hello i use this method but not worked on view

```
   @if(! auth()->user()->checkLearning($course))
                        <form action="/series/payment" method="post">
                            {{csrf_field()}}
                            <input type="hidden" name="course_id" value="{{$course->id}}">
                           <button type="submit" class="btn-tohid">خریداری این دوره</button>
                        </form>
    @else
                            <a href="#">به این دوره دسترسی دارید</a>
    @endif
```

and my model in user

```
 public function checkLearning($course)
    {
        return !! Learning::where('user_id' , $this->id)->where('course_id' , $course->id)->first();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see here, you're trying to get `checkLearning()` from user that is not logged in, hence you're getting the error. The `auth()->user()` method returns `null`, and `null` doesn't have `checkLearning()` method. Not exactly sure what you're trying to check in this condition, but if you want to check if logged in user has/doesn't have some records in `Learning` model, you need to change your condition to this:

```
@if(auth()->user() && !auth()->user()->checkLearning($course))
   //First check if user is logged in, then check if he has/doesn't have records
@else
   //Do something else                             
@endif
```

Also, I'm not sure what `!!` represents in your `checkLearning()` method, can you provide some more info what do you want to to there?

Comment: it is work thanks i add other else if for projact and this is work fine   @elseif(auth()->guest())